# How to Create a Three Level Table of Contents in Jaspersoft Studio?

Tags: jasper-reports, nested-lists, tableofcontents

I created:

- main report (chapter)

-- with sub-report (section)

--- where there is another sub-section.

Unfortunately, when I add the main report to the report book it does not appear and I do not know how to create a bookmark to section and subsection to be visible as lvl 2 and 3 in a table of contents.

**XML data source:**

```
<data>
    <chapter>
        <title>Chapter 1</title>
        <section>
            <title>Section 1.1</title>
            <subsection>
                <title>Subsection 1.1.1</title>
            </subsection>
            <subsection>
                <title>Subsection 1.1.2</title>
            </subsection>
        </section>
        <section>
            <title>Section 1.2</title>
            <subsection>
                <title>Subsection 1.2.1</title>
            </subsection>
        </section>
    </chapter>
    <chapter>
        <title>Chapter 2</title>
        <section>
            <title>Section 2.1</title>
            <subsection>
                <title>Subsection 2.1.1</title>
                <subsection>
                    <title>Subsection 2.1.1.1</title>
                </subsection>
            </subsection>
            <subsection>
                <title>Subsection 2.1.2</title>
            </subsection>
        </section>
        <section>
            <title>Section 2.2</title>
        </section>
    </chapter>
</data>
```

**main report:**

```
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 6.20.5.final using JasperReports Library version 6.20.5-3efcf2e67f959db3888d79f73dde2dbd7acb4f8e  -->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="listThree" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="d6b4833b-32f2-472a-86f2-b3ddb97df3ee">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="chatXML"/>
    <queryString language="xPath">
        <![CDATA[data/chapter]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="chapterTitle" class="java.lang.String">
        <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.xpath.field.expression" value="title"/>
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[chapterTitle]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <group name="chapterGroup" isStartNewPage="true">
        <groupExpression><![CDATA[$F{chapterTitle}]]></groupExpression>
    </group>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <detail>
        <band height="30">
            <textField bookmarkLevel="1">
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="30" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" uuid="e779eb11-4c9c-4fbb-99bc-c4f3eb0a355c"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{chapterTitle}]]></textFieldExpression>
                <anchorNameExpression><![CDATA[$F{chapterTitle}]]></anchorNameExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
        <band height="61">
            <subreport overflowType="Stretch">
                <reportElement x="20" y="0" width="535" height="60" uuid="e04dca3e-96e0-4e82-8621-725b9f71b6c5">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.element.name" value="section"/>
                </reportElement>
                <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[((net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRXmlDataSource)$P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE}).subDataSource("chapter/section")]]></dataSourceExpression>
                <subreportExpression><![CDATA["sectionSubreport.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
            </subreport>
            <break>
                <reportElement x="0" y="60" width="98" height="1" uuid="41451c94-0a60-46a6-b95e-8b7dce6145eb"/>
            </break>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

When I tested the report book on a simple table it all appeared without faults, but with nesting the 3rd degree already there are problems. I use Abstract book template and I didn't give anything new. Please help solve this problem with bookmarks and levels in the table of contents.